# certificate pinning - What happens when rogue developer gets certificate file in Android

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, pinning

In using Certification pinning development is saying that no 3rd party will be trusted with the https certificate, instead it will be stored on the device.  If i reverse engineer an android apk, would i not have access to this certificate ? I realize its public but i could use it to do man in the middle attacks, correct ? Where should i put the certificate so that no one can access it ? I have  *.cer certificate file located in resources folder in android but need to know how secure it will be there.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate is not secret, so don't worry about someone reverse engineering your certificate. To pin the certificate, simply embed your server's cert into your app. Then at runtime, when the server sends you it's cert, compare it to the one you embedded to ensure they are the same.  Do this in *addition* to all the usually SSL/TLS verification.

Comment: so if someone gains hold of my certificate cant they then communicate with my server ? Could you elaborate a bit more Richard ?

Comment: If your goal is to have your server communicate with only authenticated and authorized clients, that's not certificate pinning. That's client authentication. You could in fact do both, but my answer pertains to your question about certificate pinning.

Comment: Note that even with client authentication, the certificate is public, not secret. It's the key the client uses which must be kept secret. For more information see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19424-01/820-4811/aakhe/index.html.